# Server Manager For telnet

Tags: windows-10, telnet

I want to enable telnet on Windows 10.  I only see a telnet client but not a telnet server.  There is a web page telling me to open server manager and do a lot of stuff.  But, I don't have a server manager.  Please help!  I want to enable telnet.

Comment: It might be better to explain exactly why you want to run a telnet server, it's not a particularly safe protocol, its rarely used these days other than in specialist cases such as accessing switches and the like. Just trying to avoid you finding this isn't actually what you want/need.

As for why you don't have server manager, I'd expect it only exists in windows server versions, such as Windows Server 2008 and 2012 (and when it arrives 2016).

Comment: The telnet server service was removed from Windows 10 and [Windows Server 2012 R2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn303411.aspx)

Comment: To install [Telnet Client](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx), run `pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"`.

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft depreciated Telnet *Servers* in [Windows Server 2012 R2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn303411.aspx), and subsequently in Windows 10.

Telnet is considered completely insecure these days, because [it sends everything across the wire in plain text](http://www.packetu.com/2012/04/17/whats-wrong-with-telnet/), so they removed it.

Since you'd need to install a [3rd party Telnet server](http://www.georgiasoftworks.com/products/uts/overview.php), you should (instead) consider installing a SSH server. Similar abilities and results, but SSH is generally considered secure.

Perhaps check out this Serverfault question for some suggested SSH servers:

[What is a good SSH server to use on Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

#### Windows 8 (2012)

To install telnet in Windows 8, you can use `pkgmgr` command in the CMD terminal:

- [Telnet Client](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771275(v=ws.10)): `pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"`
- [Telnet Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc770501(v=ws.10)): `pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetServer"`

> Applies To: Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Vista

#### Windows 10

In Windows 10, `pkgmgr` is deprecated, so use `dism` instead, e.g.

- Telnet Client: `dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient`
- Telnet Client: `dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetServer`

To disable, use `/Disable-Feature` param instead.

---

Related:

- [Using Command Prompt To Install Telnet Client On Windows](https://www.walkernews.net/2014/01/01/using-command-prompt-to-install-telnet-client-on-windows/)
- [Enable Telnet through Command Prompt or Control Panel in Windows 10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-enable-telnet-through-command-prompt-windows-7)